# incompatible types error in linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list

```
public static Node stringToList(String s) {
    Node<Character> head = new Node<Character>();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    head = new Node<Character>(s.charAt(i), head);
    }
    char c = head.item;      // error line
}



I am trying to convert the char value in the nodes to an integer value and I believe I have found a way to do so. Just want to store the item in nodes to variable c for the time being. And then I got the error message. 
Why am I getting an incompatible types error? And it says "required: character".

// Node class:
public class Node<Item> {
    public Item item;           //as you can see, it a generic class
    public Node<Item> next;
    Node() { 
        item = null; 
        next = null;      
    } 
    Node(Item i) {
        item = i;
        next = null;
    }
    Node(Item i, Node<Item> p) {
        item = i;
        next = p;
    }
}
```

### full error message: File: /Users/Michelle/BigInt.java [line: 11] Error: /Users/Michelle/BigInt.java:11: incompatible types found : java.lang.Object required: char

Comment: Could you point out where you're getting the "required: character" error?
Also possibly show your Node class

Comment: I suspect you're also getting a longer error message which shows what the *actual* type is. Please show the *full* error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:
based on your new edit including the error message, this is probably what you're doing

```
Integer oneBoxed = 1;
char d = (char) oneBoxed; //error... required: char, found: Integer
```

what  you should do is

```
Integer oneBoxed = 1;
char d = (char) oneBoxed.intValue();
```

Be careful when working with Generics because you are forced to box all primitives.

You're new here but please try to post more information when asking questions ;-)

---original answer---

I'm relatively certain that you're trying to

1. cast a Boxed Character into a Boxed Integer.
   OR
2. cast a Boxed Integer into a Boxed Character.

You to perform a cast from Character to Integer, you must first unbox them first.

```
Integer one = 1;
Character b = one;
    //Error will be
    //
    //required: Character
    //found: Integer
```

The other way around

```
Character c = 'c';
Integer cInt =  c;
    //Error will be
    //
    //required: Integer
    //found: Character
```

To properly cast these values, you'll need to unbox the rValue first.

```
Integer one = 1;
Character b = (char) one.intValue();
//Yay! No Error
```

and

```
Character c = 'c';
Integer cInt = (int) c.charValue();
//Yay! No Error Again!
```